# ¿Cómo mostrar 5 productos por cada categoría?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un foreach que me trae todas las categorias, necesito mostrar 5 productos de cada categoria con el siguiente formato

```
@foreach ($collection as $item)

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="product-box color">{{item 1}}</div>
            <div class="product-box color">{{item 2}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="product-box color">{{item 3}}</div>                              
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="product-box color">{{item 4}}</div>
           <div class="product-box color">{{item 5}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eso no necesitas un foreach, simplemente accede a cada elemento en el array (colección):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="product-box color">{{ $collection[0] }}</div>
        <div class="product-box color">{{ $collection[1] }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="product-box color">{{ $collection[2] }}</div>                              
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="product-box color">{{ $collection[3] }}</div>
       <div class="product-box color">{{ $collection[4] }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Necesito mostrar 5 productos de cada categoría, lo de arriba es para mostrar solo 5 productos de una categoría, imagina que necesito mostrar 4 categorías mas con sus 5 respectivos productos cada categoría

Comment: Entonces está mal planteada la pregunta, si lees lo que escribiste, te darías cuenta que estás explicando algo muy distinto.

Answer (score 0):

$collection son tus categorías?
donde tienes la relación de categorías a producto en tu modelo lo deberías de tener un HasMany
Ejemplo del modelo Categoría:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Categoria extends Model
    {
        //
        public function productos()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Producto::class,'id','categoria_id');
        }
    }
```

Vista .blade:
    `@foreach ($collection as $item)
       @for($i=0,$i<5,$i++)
         @foreach ($item->productos as $prod)
           @if($i<5)
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-box color">{{$prod 1}}</div>
                <div class="product-box color">{{$prod 2}}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="product-box color">{{$prod 3}}</div>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="product-box color">{{$prod 4}}</div>
               <div class="product-box color">{{$prod 5}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          @endif
        @endforeach
      @endfor
    @endforeach`